# Differentiating a mapping f: Mat(m,n) to Mat(k,l)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, vector-analysis, linear-transformations

How can one define differentiability at a point for A in Mat(m,n) for the mapping of Mat(m,n) to Mat(k,l)?  I am having a hard time forming an appropriate picture in my head, other than to say that maybe the standard matrix difference quotient suffices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No. Do you know the derivative for a vector valued function? $Mat(m,n)$ is isometric to the $mn$ tuple space.

Comment: So I should think of Mat(m,n) as a space R^mn?

Comment: yes. It is the best to compute the derivative as partial differential or as linear map. The Jacobian isn't really a matrix, or you need to identify the matrices with tuples.